# swap string positions around a word in C?

Tags: c

My problem is I have an input say :

```
# ## abc ###
```

and my output should be:

```
### abc # ##
```

What I do is I loop through the input and whenever I find a character before the english word, the english word and the characters after the english words in respective previously initialized array using the following part of my algorithm:

```
char before[before_size],after[after_size],word[word_size];
word_found = 0;
if(flag == 1){
    for(j = 0;j<strlen(word_arr);j++){
        if(isalpha(*(word_arr+j)) == 0 && word_found == 0){
            before[b_counter] = *(word_arr+j);
            b_counter++;
            //"I am inserting elements in the before array!\n");
        }else if(isalpha(*(word_arr+j)) != 0){
                 word[word_counter] = *(word_arr+j);
                 word_found = 1;
                 word_counter++;
                 //"I am inserting elements in the word array!\n");
        }else if(isalpha(*(word_arr+j))== 0 && word_found == 1){
                 after[a_counter]= *(word_arr+j);
                 a_counter++;
                 //"I am inserting elements in the after array!\n");
        }
    }
    printf("%s %s %s",after,word,before);
}
```

word_arr is basically the user input.
But the output is skewed because that's what I get as an output:

```
###> abc > # ## r"u6@wI  # ## abc ###
```

What are those rubbish the computer is outputting?Where are they coming from??

Answer (score 2):

> What are those rubbish the computer is outputting?

That's the characters from uninitialized part of the string in character arrays `before`, `word`, and `after`. `printf`'s `%s` does not know where the initialized part ends, so it goes on until it finds `'\0'` character.

> Where are they coming from?

The cause is missing null terminators. Add them after the loop as follows:

```
before[b_counter] = '\0';
word[word_counter] = '\0';
after[a_counter] = '\0';
```

Comment: Yes that solves the strange characters popping up! My other concern that now the output is 

     ## abc # 
with a space in the very begging of the sentence because I included it in my "After" array. Any idea how to remove it so that my output starts from the beginning with a space in the very beginning?

Comment: as you want to add an extra character at the end of each string (char-array), you have to allocate an extra index for each of your strings (char-arrays). So each char-array needs to be expanded with 1 extra place

Comment: @MahmoudAyman Your code is a simple state machine; you need to add one more state to it - after the word but before the suffix. Make an `after_found` flag, and set it to one when you see the first character that is not `isspace(...)` following the word. I imagine you have a similar issue with the trailing space of `before[...]`.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight isspace() function will simplify the whole algorithm so much man thank you for your help!